# Redhat not booting on an HP Itanium

Tags: redhat, boot, itanium

I've inherited a number of different systems to administer.  One of them is an HP Itanium running a version of Redhat.  Today the system died and when I try to reboot selecting RedHat from the EFI Boot Manager, I got the message saying that the Load of Redhat failed: Not found.

I'm confused as to how to diagnose the problem from here.

It would appear to me, that the first disk (the /boot/efi) is on /dev/sda1 has died and needs to be replaced.  The other second disk (/dev/sdb1) is the root disk.  I know this from a similarly provisioned HP Itanium system which is its twin.

If this is the only problem, any suggestions on the quickest way to recover.....aside from reinstallation of RH after the disk replacement.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you try booting from a live CD and inspecting the had disks ?

Answer (score 0):

If the hdd containing your /boot partition is dead, then your only solution is to boot with a live cd and inspect the disks from there. You could also check the boot options in the grub menu (press enter to enter grub menu, then e to edit). From there you'll be able to confirm that:

1. The boot device is indeed /dev/sda1 (would show as hd0,0)
2. That there is no typo or mistake in the kernel parameters
3. If there was a kernel update done recently, you should be able to boot from it (in case the hdd is not the issue)

You should also edit the boot options and remove the "rhgb quiet" part so that you see everything during the boot process (in case it was not the case), that might give you more clues.